# mongodb: migrate from small files to large files

Tags: mongodb

I'm going to have about 2000 databases. So I decided to start with smallfiles option. But in future out of these 2000 databases few dbs may grow to several GBs in size. I know using smallfiles for larger Dbs will affect performance. Right now I do not know which of these 2000 dbs will grow.

So in the future once few dbs grows to several GBs in size, can I convert/migrate all small files into large files? Anyone has done this before? Did you face any issues?

I'm even thinking, in the future when few Dbs grows to several GBs, migrate them to a different mongo cluster where smallfiles option is set to false.

Is it possible to have both smallfiles some DBs and large files for some Dbs in the same mongo server?

Comment: No, you can't mix and match. --smallfiles is per mongod instance

Comment: @orid I can mix and match when you migrate and copy files from one server to another server. It's just data files, why it wouldn't work?

Comment: In that case you are right, you can dump a database from a "smallfiles" instance and restore it on a "regular" instance.